# I can get a Spring @Value at one of my test classes, but can't at other

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Im testing with JUnit a project, and it will take some values from an application-test.properties.

I made a class called TestPropertiesProvider which is meant to get the values and send them to my test classes but is not working while at my test class i can get the values with no problem!

This is my test class. (Here my Value annotation is working and im getting my props).

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
// The annotations SpringBootTest, and TestPropertySource, shouldn't be here, just put them to see if i could
// get the values here.
public class ODServiceImplTest {

    @Value("${ondemand.server.port}")String si; // THIS IS WORKING, BUT I DONT WANNA USE THE @Value HERE!
    ODService odService = new ODServiceImpl();
TestPropertiesProvider propsProvider = new TestPropertiesProvider();

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(odService, "converterFactory", new ConverterFactory());
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(odService, "SERVER_NAME", propsProvider.getSERVER_NAME());
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(odService, "SERVER_PORT", propsProvider.getSERVER_PORT());
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(odService, "USER_ID", propsProvider.getUSER_ID());
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(odService, "PASSWORD", propsProvider.getPASSWORD());
}

@Test
void getDocumentDtoByValueTest() {
...
...
```

And this is my TestPropertiesProvider class, i want my values to be taken here, so with the getters i can use them here.

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@Component
public class TestPropertiesProvider {

    // Connection params.
    @Value("${ondemand.server.port}")String si; // THIS IS NOT WORKING, I WANT THIS TO WORK.
    private final String USER_ID = "DH01A";
    private final String PASSWORD = "AR2SB";
    private final String SERVER_NAME = "servername...";
    private final String SERVER_PORT = "1415";

    // Example values for OnDemand searchs.
    private final String CORRECT_FOLDER_NAME = "DECF001";
    private final String CORRECT_FOLDER_NAME_2 = "DH0001";
    private final String NRO_ENVIO_SEARCH_VALUE = "20180500022E";
    private final String NRO_ENVIO_SEARCH_FIELD = "NRO_ENVIO";
    private final String PDF_FORMAT = "PDF";

    // Utility methods and getters...
    ...
    ...
```

Hope anybody can help me, thanks! I'm using Spring Boot and JUnit 5.

**UPDATE**: The not working @Value 's are setting null at the variables.
My both java classes are at the same application, at 'src/test/java/' but at differents packages. My application have only one 'application-test.properties' at my 'src/test/resources/ folder.

Comment: *// THIS IS NOT WORKING, I WANT THIS TO WORK.* - how is it not working? Is it null? Is it crashing - what?  Are `ODServiceImplTest ` and `TestPropertiesProvider` is the same application? package? Do you have more than one `application-test.properties` file ?

Comment: Sorry for the little information, i just updated the post.

Comment: Can you show your main function please.

Comment: Your test should not be a Spring `@Component`; it is outside your main code, making operations on it.

Comment: Foxhound, I don't know what do you refer when you say my main function. Is it not Java project, it's a spring boot.

Comment: chrylis, i tried it without the @Component and the result it was the same, i added the component later to autowire it the provider on my test class.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work. You are creating instances yourself, those are outside the scope of Spring. Why are you instantiating a test class, which should be a component? And why on earth this ugly contraption of a test? This beats the purpose of `@SpringBootTest`. Instead you should let spring Boot (or the spring test context framework) handle that for you; Looks like you are trying to outsmart the testing framework instead of working with the framework.

Comment: Like i said at other commnt, i already tried it using the @Autowired in place of instancing the class, but result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i could solve it, adding the annotation @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS).

This way:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Component
public class TestPropertiesProvider {
    ...
    ...
```

I really don't know how is this working, but solved me problem. I would really appreciate if somebody can explain it to me! Searching at Docs says that my instance will be just one of TestPropertiesProvider for all my tests, but that doesn't explain the problem I got.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ODServiceImplTest` class your are creating an instance of `TestPropertiesProvider` class manually instead of using spring dependency injection mechanism.

So this will not inject the value of `ondemand.server.port` property in `si` variable. Instead you need to autowire `TestPropertiesProvider` in `ODServiceImplTest` as below.

```
@Autowired 
TestPropertiesProvider propsProvider;
```